# New Window in Structural Brick House

Tags: windows, brick, structural

I have an old house (built in the 1940s) that is structural brick. I want to add a small window on the wall to the upstairs to let in a bit more light. Is it possible to add a window to a structural brick house? What special considerations would I have to take?

Answer (score 2):

Anything can be done but it's hard for me to believe this is a DIY project. You will need to find a way to bridge over the window with an arch or header in such a way that the load is adequately supported. Also if the wall is important to the lateral strength of the building (and an exterior solid masonry wall probably is), you need to make sure the entire opening is framed out in a way that doesn't affect the shear strength of the wall.